# vim airline symbols doesn't display well & why guifontwide display is right only when I reload vimrc

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-airline

[image: not display well see the right of picture]

I set right font( power line font name "hack") and

```
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
```

but I don's know why the right corner not display well like left.
I try to set font size and other font family or update airline.But no help on this problem.

---

Another question was I set guifont and guifontwide but, only I reload the vimrc file vim will work right and display right font.It like that

this is vim when i not reload vimrc
[image: Launch vim(not reload vimrc)]

and this is when i reload vimrc
[image]

---

MacVim Version 8.0 (121) on OSX 10.11.6

Comment: Can you try putting this in your vimrc?   `let g:airline#extensions#whitespace#mixed_indent_algo = 1`

Comment: Also some fonts might work better than others

Comment: @sudobangbang It's not work.And i try 3 kind of fonts can's fix problem.
And very thank you help me fix my grammatical errors, Really.

Comment: @Horizon_Net may I ask for your help?